# Firebase Promise not executing

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, promise, firebase-authentication

I have the following method:

```
    async signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(
        response => {
            console.log(response);
            return firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
        }
    )
    .then(
        (token: string) => {
            this.token = token;
            return true;
        }
    )
    .catch(
        error => {
            console.log(error);
            return false;
        }
    );
}
```

This method is called from a componente like this:

```
  onSignin(form: NgForm) {
const email = form.value.email;
const password = form.value.password;

this.authService.signinUser(email, password)
.then(
  (result: boolean) => {
    console.log(result);
    if (result) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
    }
  }
);
```

}

The component method is called from the onsubmit of a form.

The log does not show anything, for some reason the promises are not executing. Can anyone help me?

Cheers

Comment: Are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: Did you miss to `preventDefault()` the onsubmit event navigating away?

Comment: The console shows nothng, and the network tab doesn't show any petition to firebase. I reverted the changes and did it again and now it's working... pretty strange

Comment: I have imported the FormsModule, so I think preventDefault() is not needed. Anyway it is working now so I will mark it as resolved

Answer (score 1):

I reverted the changes and did it again and now it's working